# Why else block is not working when a ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I posted username to php file and recieve data form it using ajax .In this code if block is working but else block don't work. When I change the if condtion **data!= null** to **data== null**, then also if block only works. I have no idea what wrong with it the code seems to be correct even I added ajax plugins also.

Here is the code block

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#username').keyup(function(){
        var username = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                url:'admin_reg_validation.php',
                method:"POST",
                data:{user_name:username},
                success:function(data){
                    if(data!=null){
                        $('#user_info').css("color","red");
                        $('#user_info').html("username is already in use");
                        document.getElementById("submitbtn").disabled = true;
                    }else{
                        $('#user_info').css("color","green");
                        $('#user_info').html("username is available"); 
                        document.getElementById("submitbtn").disabled = false;
                    }
                }

            });
        });
    });
```

Can you offer any assistance. Its very worthwhile for me. Thank you!

Comment: Have you done `console.log(data);` to check what `data` actually contains. What you're saying doesn't appear to make sense on the surface, but we need to investigate fully and understand what the data you're working with it, before we can even attempt to reproduce such an issue.

Comment: are you saying both `if(data!=null){` and `if(data==null){` are true?

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for your comment I never use console.log() before. Now I try it and figure out the error and solve it. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. You can also use the debugger in your developer tools, and for ajax-related stuff the Network tool is also a useful window into what's happening with code and requests in your browser. These are all vital tools you need to be familiar with when writing JavaScript code. I am a bit surprised you got as far as writing code like this without ever encountering it!

Comment: I second ADyson's suggestion to use developer tools, network tab. Maybe server returns malformed JSON or an empty response? According to jQuery ajax() documentation https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-url-settings that would actually throw an error "The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected". Therefore I suggest you also implement an "error" callback and see whether that gets called.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the server returns malformed JSON or an empty response if the user doesn't exist yet?
According to jQuery ajax() documentation https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-url-settings that would actually throw an error

> "The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is
> rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty
> response is also rejected".

Therefore I suggest you also implement an `error` callback and see whether that gets called and what exactly the error is that you get, if user doesn't exist. Then modify the `if` condition in the error callback so the code executes only for non-existent user, but not on other types of error.

Another possibility is that the server replies with an empty object `{}`. This would likely go into the `success` callback and execute in the `if` statement (not else). So you may check for an empty `data` object as well, using jQuery `isEmptyObject()`.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/#jQuery-isEmptyObject-object

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#username').keyup(function(){
        var username = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                url:'admin_reg_validation.php',
                method:"POST",
                data:{user_name:username},
                success:function(data){
                    // let's see what server responses we actually get:
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); 
                    // presumably an emtpy object indicates a non-existant user, so check for that as well
                    if(data && !isEmptyObject(data)) {
                        
                        $('#user_info').css("color","red");
                        $('#user_info').html("username is already in use");
                        document.getElementById("submitbtn").disabled = true;
                    }else{
                        $('#user_info').css("color","green");
                        $('#user_info').html("username is available"); 
                        document.getElementById("submitbtn").disabled = false;
                    }
                },
                error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    // let's see what server responses we actually get:
                    console.log("textStatus="+textStatus+" error="+errorThrown);
                    if(true) {  // modify condition to check for correct error that occurs when user doesn't exist
                        $('#user_info').css("color","green");
                        $('#user_info').html("username is available"); 
                        document.getElementById("submitbtn").disabled = false;
                    }
                }

            });
        });
    });
```